# Using performselector - twice for the same method

Tags: ios, xcode, performselector

Im trying to call this method twice using perform selector

```
-(void)time:(UILabel *)label{


  float duration = (label.frame.size.width + self.view.frame.size.width)/111;
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
  [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1e100f];
  label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x , label.center.y +700);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

using perform selector but only once it is being called.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(time:) withObject:testLabel afterDelay:0];

[self performSelector:@selector(time:) withObject:testLabel1 afterDelay:5];
```

Only the first one is called. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: use timer 2 call function twice after 2 time invalidate the timer

Comment: Check if the you are calling the second one when the first one is still in progress. You may not be able to run 2 animations at a time like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timer 2 call function twice after 2 time invalidate the timer

Comment: The 2 calls have different arguments.

Comment: i get this error : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer frame]